# this.states initialized by separate function from out of constructor in Reactjs

Tags: react-router, reactjs, reactjs-flux

> Sometimes all this.states initialized by separate function from out of
>   constructor in Reactjs. May i know why?

For example:

```
class Articles extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initializer();
    }
    initializer(){
        this.state = {
            selectedArticle: this.props.article[0],
            showArticleDetails: true,
            showArticleContent: false
        };
    }
}
```

After that `this.initializer();` used wherever we need.

Comment: You should also pass props through as a parameter and use that instead of `this.props` btw.

Comment: thank u but i cant get u exactly. can u code something briefly here?

Comment: What he is saying is you should pass props in as an argument for initializer: 
`constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initializer(props);
    }
    initializer(props){
        this.state = {
            selectedArticle: props.article[0],
            showArticleDetails: true,
            showArticleContent: false
        };
    }`

Comment: thank u..great expalanation u both..

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of preference on the part of the developer. The state could have been initialized inside constructor(), but in this case the developer has chosen to put the initialization code in a separate function for clarity. It has the same effect.

BTW, you state that 'this.initializer() used wherever we need.' Once you call initializer() from the constructor, you should not call it again. Instead, you should use

```
this.setState({ newKey: newValue, ...})
```

Comment: ok ok..then how to call/use 'this.initializer()' in another component